# How to skip errors and make while-loop continue to work in R?

Tags: r

I am running a ks-test on a matrix (3723 x 223) using a `while-loop`.

In the matrix, each cell has NA or specific numeric values.

Most rows have enough numbers of cell to conduct ks-test.

However, some rows have too small number or NA values to conduct ks-test.
This terminates my while loop (When my test reached the 1359th row).

Followings are my while loop code and error message.

```
while(x<3724){  
 results[x,1]=  
 ks.test(as.numeric(SW480ks[x,]), as.numeric(SW620ks[x,]))$p.value  
 x=x+1  
 }

Error in ks.test(as.numeric(SW480ks[x, ]), as.numeric(SW620ks[x, ])) :   
  'x' is not enough data  
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

I want to make my code skip the problematic rows when there is an error message.

I guess that I need to use if statement but I have no idea to write.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Odd, I cannot generate this error at all, even if I give `ks.test` a single data point. That said, this is *really* not a suitable application for a `while` loop. Use `apply` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `try()` or `tryCatch()`

```
while(x < 3724){  
  test <- try(ks.test(as.numeric(SW480ks[x, ]), as.numeric(SW620ks[x, ])))
  results[x, 1] <- ifelse(class(test) == "try-error", NA, test$p.value)
  x <- x + 1  
}
```